# How do target selectors work in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On [Commands#Target selectors on the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors), it says that `r` and `rm` are used instead of `distance` in Bedrock Edition to target players by distance. However, that section is incomplete for the Bedrock Edition and does not provide any information about it. It also doesn't explain how `c` (limit), `l` and `lm` (experience level), `rx` and `rxm` (x-rotation), and `ry` and `rym` (y-rotation) work.

How do these target selectors work in Bedrock Edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` and `rm` stand for "radius maximum" and "radius minimum," respectively.  Therefore, the following target selector in Java Edition:

```
@e[distance = 5..10]
```

is equivalent to the following target selector in Bedrock Edition:

```
@e[r = 10, rm = 5]
```

Similarly goes:

- `l` and `lm` stand for "experience level maximum" and "experience level minimum," equivalent to `level` in Java Edition;
- `rx` and `rxm` stand for "rotation X maximum" and "rotation X minimum," equivalent to `x_rotation` in Java Edition. (`ry` and `rym` are analogous)

`c` stands for "count," equivalent to `limit` in Java Edition.

---

Here is the complete table from Minecraft Wiki, including some of the parameters you didn't mention:

[image]

Comment: There is even more information that is left out in the other answer. Using data I got from messing arround with command blocks, I've made a rotation compass for ry & rym command. +x = -90. +z = 0. -x = 90 -z=180/-180. There is a limit of -180 through 180.